# No suitable driver java.sql.SQLException

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a database via Java from Eclipse

Here is the code that I use for the connection :

```
 connection  = DriverManager.getConnection(general.Constants.DATABASE_CONNECTION, general.Constants.DATABASE_USER, general.Constants.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
 query       = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

 general.Constants.DATABASE_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarie"
 final public static String      DATABASE_USER           = "root";
 final public static String      DATABASE_PASSWORD       = "******";
```

When I connect to the database through *MYSQL Workbench*, I get no problems connecting to localhost with 3306 port.

I still get this error: `"java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarie"`

I read a few simillar threads and most of them point to the URL beeing the problem.

I need help identifing the problem. Will provide additional information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide the MySQL jar driver to your application. Make sure is in its build path. If this is a web application, you should just drop this jar in *WEB-INF/lib* folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the database driver is present in the classpath. Also looking at the code, i dont see where are you loading the driver. Please load the driver if you are not already doing that. Use Class.forName() to load the driver.
In your situation it would look like this:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Comment: `Class.forName()` is no longer needed for current JDBC 4 aware drivers (which includes the current MySQL driver). The .jar just needs to be on the classpath.

Comment: Indeed the driver was not int the classpath.It works now.No loading the driver needed.Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 1):

Download the MySQL driver .jar file from [the MySQL download site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) if you dont already have it.

Make sure that the jar is available on your classpath. You can use this line to do so:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar
```